# Why is there a box in Detective Charles Boyle's pants?

Tags: plot-explanation, brooklyn-nine-nine

15 minutes into the Brooklyn Nine-Nine episode "Cheddar" (s3, e18), Charles is lying on a coffee table, which then collapses. It's obvious he has a rectangular box or book in the seat of his sweatpants. No one mentions it. Was there a deleted scene that explained the rectangle in his sweatpants?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most likely it's just something to provide a degree of protection when he fell onto the table, or when the table collapses.  Or he's just got an incredibly square ass.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the previous episodes, all the girls who dated Charles always commented that he had a perfect, bubbly ass. So in this scenario, the ass can't be an explanation.

When you see behind the scenes of Brooklyn 99, you find out that it's actually a sponge protection for Charles, since he was falling a lot in this episode.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/49).